# CASE en MySQL: Restringir valores devueltos

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas relacionadas entre sí dentro de un BBDD MySQL más amplia: ticket, ticket_generic_data (que viene a ser una tabla de paso con un atributo "value" adicional) y generic. Me interesan específicamente los tickets con una generic_id concreta que indica que han sido enviados a una app que procesa encuestas; además, si el envío ha podido ser procesado correctamente, ese "value" del que hablaba toma un 1 y si no, un 0.

Lo que quiero hacer es un CASE, de manera que si el ticket tiene la id apropiada (pongamos 3) y value 1, devuelva "correcto"; si generic_id es 3 y value 0, "fallido"; y si el ticket no se corresponde con esa generic_id, "no enviado".

El problema es que un mismo ticket puede tener diferentes generic_id (o incluso no tener ninguna), que hacen referencia a distintos parámetros, de manera que si hago el CASE tal que así:

```
SELECT a.id AS ticket_id, b.generic_id, b.value,
CASE
    WHEN generic_id = 3 AND value = 1 THEN 'Correcto'
    WHEN generic_id = 3 AND value = 0 THEN 'Fallido'
    ELSE 'No enviado'
END AS envio
FROM ticket AS a LEFT JOIN ticket_generic_data AS b ON a.id = b.ticket_id 
                 LEFT JOIN generic AS c ON b.generic_id = c.id;
```

Obtengo más registros que tickets, ya que algunos tickets salen a la vez como no enviados (cuando tienen otra generic_id distinta de 3) y como correctos/fallidos. Por ejemplo:

```
ticket_id generic_id value envio
1         1          0     No enviado
1         3          1     Correcto
2         3          0     Fallido
3         2          0     No enviado
3         4          0     No enviado
4         1          0     No enviado
4         2          0     No enviado
4         3          1     Correcto
5         NULL       0     No enviado
```

Supongo que haya que trocear esto en subconsultas, pero es un tema en el que estoy muy verde y no sé por dónde empezar. A ver si me podéis orientar.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes tener más de un envío por ticket?

Comment: No, el ticket se envía o no se envía; si tiene generic_id 3 la tiene sólo una vez, y lo mismo con el resto de generic_id: un mismo ticket puede tener varias distintas (de hecho hay bastantes más de 4 en la tabla generic), pero son valores únicos para cada ticket (puede ser 1, 5, 7 y 8, pero no 8 dos veces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un colega del trabajo dio con una solución mucho más sencilla:

```
SELECT t.id AS ticket_id, 
     CASE WHEN tgd.valor = 1 THEN 'Enviado - Correcto' 
          WHEN tgd.valor = 0 THEN 'Enviado - Fallido' 
          ELSE 'No enviado' END AS status
     FROM ticket t 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_generic_data AS tgd 
          ON t.id = tgd.ticket_id AND tgd.generic_id = 3
     ORDER BY ticket_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Conceptualmente tienes dos estados distintos, pero para entenderlo es un poco más fácil verlo como un único estado con 3 posibilidades:

- Enviado - Correcto
- Enviado - Fallido
- No enviado

Los tickets que cumplen los 2 primeros valores son todos aquellos que tengan `generic_id = 3`, es decir los enviados, el siguiente valor lo podemos ver como todos los tickets que no están en el anterior conjunto. Pensándolo de esta forma, es más sencillo plantear la solución en SQL.

```
-- Todos los tickets enviados
-- Atención: se asume que solo hay un generic_id = 3 por ticket
SELECT  a.id AS ticket_id, 
        CASE WHEN b.value = 1 THEN 'Enviado - Correcto' ELSE 'Enviado - Fallido' END 'Estado'
    FROM ticket AS a 
    LEFT JOIN ticket_generic_data AS b 
        ON a.id = b.ticket_id 
    LEFT JOIN generic AS c 
        ON b.generic_id = c.id
    WHERE b.generic_id = 3

UNION

-- Todos los tickets que no hayan sido enviados (no están en el grupo anterior)
SELECT  a1.id AS ticket_id, 
        'No enviado'
    FROM ticket AS a1
    where a1.id NOT IN (    SELECT  a.id
                    FROM ticket AS a 
                    LEFT JOIN ticket_generic_data AS b 
                        ON a.id = b.ticket_id 
                    LEFT JOIN generic AS c 
                        ON b.generic_id = c.id
                    WHERE b.generic_id = 3)
;
```

Comment: La consulta funciona para unos pocos registros pero con la cantidad que existen en la BBDD auténtica... "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Comment: Seguramente un Timeout, pasado un tiempo, la conexión se corta. Puedes aumentar este tiempo de tiemout para que la consulta finalice y analizar el plan de ejecución para entender si faltan índices. sin duda no es la consulta más óptima pero tampoco es algo enormemente complejo para el motor.